# How to change report ownership?

Tags: account-management, user-accounts, google-ad-manager

When you inactivate a username inside GAM, it automatically **cancels** all scheduled reports which that user once set up for **other** people.

Is there a way to just change the relevant reports' **ownership**, so it won't appear as **Old - keep deactivated**?

[image: Cancelled GAM reports]

[image: GAM report ownership]

[image: GAM e-mail recipients]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish it by duplicating the reports, but it's not straightforward.

You might want to keep the original reports in 1 browser tab and the the following in another:

1. Choose **Run report** over the relevant report
2. **Once it finishes loading**, click **Report builder** or **Edit**
3. Choose the same name for the report
4. Re-add the original editors/recipients and **Save**
5. Delete the original report

Screenshots:

1.

[image: Run Report over the relevant GAM report]

2.

[image: Choose Report Builder]

3.

[image: Choose a name for the GAM report]

4.

[image: Re-add GAM editors and recipients]

5.

[image]